# C++11 regex::icase inconsistent behavior

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc, gcc5.2

Coming from perl-like regular expressions, I expected the below code to match regex'es in all 8 cases. But it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void check(const string& s, regex re) {
    cout << s << " : " << (regex_match(s, re) ? "Match" : "Nope") << endl;
}

int main() {
    regex re1 = regex("[A-F]+", regex::icase);
    check("aaa", re1);
    check("AAA", re1);
    check("fff", re1);
    check("FFF", re1);
    regex re2 = regex("[a-f]+", regex::icase);
    check("aaa", re2);
    check("AAA", re2);
    check("fff", re2);
    check("FFF", re2);
}
```

Running with gcc 5.2:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o test && ./test
aaa : Match
AAA : Match
fff : Nope
FFF : Match
aaa : Match
AAA : Match
fff : Match
FFF : Nope
```

Comment: This looks like a libstdc++ bug. I think they're only checking the first character in the specified range when checking the *other* case. See this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abe033587520eece), where I changed the range to `"C-Z"` and then `"ccc"` matches, but everything else fails. clang with libc++ behaves as you expect it to.

Comment: as a workaround we use boost::regex when compiling for gcc.

Comment: A similar issue is observed with std::regex. Use Boost if you need case insensitivity with character classes.

Comment: This is being discussed in [#71500](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71500).

Comment: Does c++ support mode modifier? You may try this workaround `(?i)[A-F]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future users, this was confirmed to be a bug, and it (and similar issues) are solved as of 8.1 according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71500#c20) thread.

I suspect that the original author had a hand in bringing attention to this, but I figured maybe we could get this closed.