# Why doesn't the icase flag for regex work correctly

Tags: c++, regex, match

This function is supposed to return the first instance of a vowel in a string, but it only works on lowercase. I thought `regex_constants::icase` was supposed to handle uppercase letters as well. Also, feel free to suggest a better way to do this.

The following returns 0 (it now returns -1) for "HAPPY" and 3 for "GRE**a**T":

```cpp
#include <regex>

int firstVowel(std::string str)
{
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex pattern("[aeiou]", std::regex_constants::icase);
    while (std::regex_search(str, match, pattern))
    {
        return match.position();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm getting the returns through main:

```cpp
std::cout << firstVowel("HAPPY") << "\n";
std::cout << firstVowel("GREaT") << "\n";
```

Comment: A simple way is `"[aAeEiIoOuU]"`. Also, use `if`, not `while`. And it seems [that works](https://ideone.com/lI74AA)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any idea why this code doesn't work (I tested `if` as well)?

Comment: You are probably using a "bad" compiler with poor `std::regex` implementation.

Comment: I'm compiling with clang and `HAPPY` generate `1` as return value, and `2` for `GREaT`

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio. Should I be using something else?

Comment: My bad, looks like match_flags as a parameter directs the match. Hopefully `(?i)` can give you an option to test which overides the icase option compiled with the regex.

Comment: @Maxt8r I get an error if I use `(?i)`

Comment: Oh, must be a JavaScript regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use that library icase: [C++11 regex::icase inconsistent behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757863/c11-regexicase-inconsistent-behavior)
it is terrible....

Instead switch the string to lowercase like so:

```
std::string data = "Abc";
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
[](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
```

If you are using non-standard ASCII chars than you are on your own, there is no upper to lower for Greek Letters, Chinese Characters, Romanian Letters, and the like....

Comment: Is there a difference in using `unsigned char` vs `char`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char, In your case either one works, but just for safety reasons, I use unsigned char....